# Drivers Bind Minor version is greater than the minor version of the currently Loaded KMDF library?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Windows 8.1 computer crashes right after this message apears in the Event Viewer. 
How can I debug this crash? What driver is not working?

UPDATE: completely reinstalled Windows 8.1 with a couple of Dell drivers and now getting this warning again.

UPDATE2: Dell support asked me to run a hardware test from the BIOS and everything was ok, so according to Dell it is a software issue...

UPDATE3: some drivers that are installed (with list of external drivers below):
[Audio Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=h9tcc&oscode=wb64a&productcode=xps-27-2720-aio) [Qualcomm Atheros Wireless Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=7mtrg&oscode=wb64a&productcode=xps-27-2720-aio) [Realtek Card Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=ymrx6&oscode=wb64a&productcode=xps-27-2720-aio) [Intel Rapid Storage Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=hd4nh&oscode=wb64a&productcode=xps-27-2720-aio)

```
Log Name:System, 
Source: Wdf01000  
Event ID:      1 
Task Category: None 
Level:         Warning 
Keywords:      Classic User:          N/A 
Computer:      Computer1 
Description: Drivers Bind Minor version is greater than the minor version of the currently Loaded KMDF library -- Versions: Driver Version: 1.15 Kmdf Lib. Version: 1.13. Event Xml: <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">   <System>
    <Provider Name="Wdf01000" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32775">1</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="" />
    <EventRecordID>2181986</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Computer1</Computer>
    <Security />   </System>   <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>Driver Version: 1.15 Kmdf Lib. Version: 1.13</Data>
    <Binary></Binary> </EventData> </Event>
```

Comment: I don't know which driver is giving me problems, but the ones installed are all from Dell.

Comment: I added a list of drivers which are not from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this message:

> Driver Version: 1.15 Kmdf Lib. Version: 1.13

In the
[KMDF Version History](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/kmdf-version-history)
is listed:

[image]

So it looks like you have installed a Windows 10 version 1507 driver on
Windows 8.1. If that's indeed the case, then it is no wonder that Windows crashes.

The data in the included error text doesn't permit to identify the problematic
driver.
You might find more information in the KMDF message file `%windir%\setupact.log`.
Post here anything in that file that seems relevant and is recent enough.

As the system crashes immediately after this message is posted,
you may be able to point to a device that you used just before the crash.

Another try you could do is disable the Avira antivirus or security suite,
to see if this helps.

Comment: thanks, this log file says this: AudMig: RegOpenKeyEx can't open audioendpointbuilder Upgrade key with Hresult 0x80070002. Most likely not an upgradeAudMig: RegOpenKeyEx can't open audioendpointbuilder Upgrade key with Hresult 0x80070002. Most likely not an upgradeAudMig: RegOpenKeyEx can't open audioendpointbuilder Upgrade key with Hresult 0x80070002. Most likely not an upgrade

Comment: Question : Which drivers have you installed manually?

Comment: I would still like an answer to the above message, but it's clear that something went wrong with the update. I would suggest doing a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) after downloading the latest boot media. Wait with the installation of drivers for our opinion. Windows 10 has an excellent device support and the generic drivers may be enough.

Comment: Does this arrive in vanilla Windows without the above apps?